# What are your thoughts on SKLearn's dismissal of GPUs for machine learning?

Tags: scikit-learn, gpu

SKLearn has [this broad claim](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-gpu-support) in its FAQs:

> Outside of neural networks, GPUs don’t play a large role in machine learning today, and much
>   larger gains in speed can often be achieved by a careful choice of
>   algorithms.

Anyone care to add color for or against this claim?

Comment: Could you clarify which algorithm do you think would benefit from the GPU? The linear models ones?

Comment: They are excluding anything with neural networks in the comment, so I am looking for an inventory of machine learning algorithms that are not neural networks and are uniquely resistant to being parallelized on a GPU.

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought you had models in mind. Other than neural networks, I don't know what else would benefit from vectorization. The linear models would benefit a little bit, but very little. Maybe Euclidean distances computed by kNN and k-means would benefit a little too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GPU doesn't inherently fit naturally into all machine learning algorithms.  A natural contender is one that inherently takes a myriad of matrix multiplication.  This makes sense since graphic processors inherently were design for this.  However, for an algorithm like a Random Forest this may not be so important.  Also there exist a cost to transfer information to a GPU.  Any algorithm that is O(n) should not be computed on a GPU because it takes O(n) to communicate the data.  There's a few other issues that GPU present dealing with RAM and Threading, each of which often render making a GPU variant of a project more of a hassle than it's worth.

Furthermore, adding GPU to the sklearn framework inherently adds a hardware dependency and complexity that seems needless for shallow algorithms.  Odds are, if you're needing access to your GPU, you are dealing with a neural network, which has it's own unique architecture challenges.  I think it makes far more sense to separate deep learning into it's own module (look at how huge tensorflow/pytorch/etc) project are) than force Sklearn to add hardware dependencies for marginal computational gains.